# GWT ui binder: nesting custom widgets

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have two custom widgets `Foo extends Composite` and `Bar`. I would like to nest them in my ui.xml as follows:

```
<my:Foo width="100%" ui:field="myFoo">
  <my:Bar label="someLabel"/>
</my:Foo>
```

I would expect that some method will be called on `Foo`, `addWidget` or kind of. However I get the following error:

```
Found unexpected child element Element <my:Bar label='someLabel'>
```

How could I get this fixed? Is it possible to nest my custom widgets in ui.xml?

Comment: How does your `Foo` and `Bar` look? Code please.

Comment: Nice consistency with java examples (FooBar). Remember to declare a @UiConstructor in Bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I got it: `Foo` had to implement `HasWidgets` as well!